# Same observed list in several views

Tags: java, swing

I have two views (JPanel) that uses the same domain object.  My domain object contains a `ObservableList`.

The ObservableList is a LinkedList

```
private ObservableList<MyObject> listMyObject = ObservableCollections.
    observableList(Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<MyObject>()));
```

In my two views I to do some calculation each time an element is added to the list

```
protected class MyListDataListener implements ObservableListListener {
   public void listElementsAdded(ObservableList list, int index, int length) {
   MyObject obj = (MyObject)list.get(index);
   Poin2D location = obj.getObjLocation();
   location.setLocation(location.x + (time / getWidth()), location.y);
   obj.setObjLocation(location);
}
```

The problem I have is that as both views use the same list each time one element is added to the list the location is updated two times the object that is moving in the view finish its animation two times faster.  I would like it to be updated only one time for each element added.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
public MyFrame() {
View view1 = new View(domainObject.getMyDataList());
View view2 = new View(domainObject.getMyDataList());
}
}

public class View extends JPanel {
private ObservableList<MyObject> listMyObject;
private ObservableList<MyObject> otherList = ObservableCollections.
    observableList(Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<MyObject>()));

public View(ObservableList<MyObject> listMyObject) {
this.listMyObject = listMyObject;
listMyObject.addListListener(new MyListDataListener());
}

protected class MyListDataListener implements ObservableListListener {
   public void listElementsAdded(ObservableList list, int index, int length) {
otherList.add((MyObject)list.get(index));
for(MyObject obj : otherList) {
Poin2D location = obj.getObjLocation();
   location.setLocation(location.x + (time / getWidth()), location.y);
   obj.setObjLocation(location);
}
}
```

If i don't create view2, everything is working fine.  With view2 created each time an element is added each view iteratate the list and change the location of my object two times instead of one time.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you post more of your code to show how the listener is used?

Comment: don't understand the question: if the list fires twice, something is wrong with its implementation. If the list doesn't have a getSize() - or similar - method which is correct at all times, something is wrong with its implementation as well. If you have two separate listeners for doing the relocation on the same object in the same view (?), something is wrong with the using code

Comment: I updated my exemple, I hope you can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I don't understand what you expect:

- you have a master list (myListData)
- you have two listeners on that master list
- you have two copies of that list (otherList) containing the *same* instances as the master
- on receving an add, each of the two listeners manipulates the elements in the the copy: those elements are the *same* instances as in the master, so they manipulated twice ..

To solve, do the manipulation of the elements once outside of the view, f.i. by keeping the listener outside:

```
// frame
getDataList().addListener(....);
new View(getDataList());
// view
... do nothing
```

Comment: Yes ok, that is what i will try to do then, but it is annoying to move the listener outside the view to get the element for my calculation.  Annoying but possible, so i'll do it this way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you could get the size of the list from the ObservableList directly, using some built in method (size())?, rather than having to keep a separate 'count' variable. (Depending on what implementation this `ObservableList` class this is.)

Comment: The ObservableList implementation is a LinkedList.  And the calculation is a bit more complex than just count++, and the size of the list is not useful in this case.  I updated my question.